# How to separate data from large tsv file based on conditions and write on another file using Linux command

Tags: linux, csv

I have a tsv file named  `userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv` of more than 2 GB of size with the following data

```
user_000022  2007-08-26T20:11:33Z   ede96d89-515f-4b00-9635-2c5‌​‌​f5a1746fb    The Aislers Set  9eed842d-5a1a-42c8-9788-0a11e818f35c   The Red Door 

user_000022  2007-08-26T20:09:17Z   2aca01cc-256e-4a0d-b337-2be‌​263ef9302  All Girl Summer Fun Band    722bd5fd-1b27-4ec1-ba21-3e7dc3c514b0    Cut Your Hair 

user_000022  2007-08-26T20:06:07Z   606da894-aa6e-4a13-b253-e37‌​‌​b4403e9fc    Sambassa‌​de‌​ur    9af3dae2-f73e‌​-43b‌​e-9784-85d9c16‌​90b38  ‌​Whatever Season
```

Consider the first input line: Where first column is `userid` i.e. `user_000022`, second column is `timestamp` i.e. `2007-08-26T20:11:33Z`, third column is `artid` i.e. `ede96d89-515f-4b00-9635-2c5‌​‌​f5a1746fb`, fourth column is the `artname` i.e. `The Aislers Set`, fifth column is the `traid` i.e `9eed842d-5a1a-42c8-9788-0a11e818f35c` and sixth column is the `traname` i.e `The Red Door` Here each column is `TAB` saperated.

My goal is to process it and create a file with the following format:

```
useridi<TAB>traidi1 traidi2 ...
```

where `useridi` is the `ith` user and `traidij` is the `jth` track id that will contain only the songs that each user has listened at least 20 times. So every line must contain all the tracks
that a user has listened to at least 20 times, and each track id of those must appear just once.

I want know how to write Linux command for this since I am using Linux for the first time. I only know how to separate column using awk.

Comment: do you want to print word `track` in output as well ?

Comment: No. Need to print only song ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sample data doesn't have condition that satisfies your spec, so I used 0 as the threshold, also assumes trackIds are unique, otherwise use a composite key (songId,trackId). File doesn't need to be sorted...

```
awk      '{user[$1];track[$4];count[$1,$4]++}
      END {for(u in user) 
             {sep="\t";
              for(t in track) 
                {if(count[u,t]>0) 
                   {if(sep=="\t") {printf "%s",u sep; sep=OFS}
                    printf "%s", sep t}}
           printf "%s", ORS}}' file
```

gives

```
002  id_05 idRC id2
001  id_01 id2
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

using your updated file and editing for the format, this script produces the listed output

```
sed -r 's/  +/\t/g' file   |  # you won't need this step for tsv format
awk -F'\t' '{print $1,$5}' | 
sort                       | 
uniq -c                    |
awk '$1<1  {next}
     $2==p {tracks=tracks FS $3} 
     $2!=p {if(tracks) print tracks; p=$2; tracks=p "\t" $3}
     END   {print tracks}'
```

output

```
user_000022 722bd5fd-1b27-4ec1-ba21-3e7dc3c514b0 9af3dae2-f73e‌​-43b‌​e-9784-85d9c16‌​90b38 9eed842d-5a1a-42c8-9788-0a11e818f35c
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My real file has big data, it's a file of more than 2GB of size. When I used your solution, I found following error: "Value too large for defined data type".

Comment: if so, then it will be easier to sort it first by user - trackID and filter the values less than the threshold.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this with my original input file but there is no result and no error. I'm giving you the link of my original file as follows : http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~ocelma/MusicRecommendationDataset/lastfm-1K.html from this link you can download "lastfm-dataset-1K.tar.gz" inside this there is a file named "userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv" and this is my main input file, here columns are ordered as per the file name. I tried to run this script several time by changing parameters and each time it increased my vdi file size of Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty 32 bit.

Comment: if your input file is tab separated remove the `-d' '` from the `cut` command.  For the future make sure the sample input you post is representative of your data...

Comment: get a portion of the file with `head -100` or similar and inspect whether the file is tab separated or not (`cat -A`), perhaps the extension is not correct.  You can also inspect the values after each pipe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I apologies for the sample input, I did this because my file is so large that I can't open it. I did the following changes: 'cut -f1,5 userid-timestamp-artid-artname-traid-traname.tsv | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1<20 {next} $2==p {tracks=tracks $6 FS; next}{print tracks; p=$2; tracks$2 "\t"} END {print track}' > myfile.tsv' but it's still not working.

Comment: Yes it is tab separated. My input file extension is .tsv. These are some input from the file: `user_000022 2007-08-26T20:11:33Z ede96d89-515f-4b00-9635-2c5‌​f5a1746fb The Aislers Set 9eed842d-5a1a-42c8-9788-0a11e818f35c The Red Door user_000022 2007-08-26T20:09:17Z 2aca01cc-256e-4a0d-b337-2be‌​263ef9302 All Girl Summer Fun Band 722bd5fd-1b27-4ec1-ba21-3e7dc3c514b0 Cut Your Hair user_000022 2007-08-26T20:06:07Z 606da894-aa6e-4a13-b253-e37‌​b4403e9fc Sambassade‌​ur 9af3dae2-f73e-43b‌​e-9784-85d9c1690b38 ‌​Whatever Season`

Comment: number of fields don't match.  Please post the data formatted in the question area.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the input file sample. One thing to notice here that the track name contain multiple words that are space separated although we have to consider them as a single value for traname column. Same for the artname column. That's why you are getting number of field doesn't match. I have added the sample data that might not be tab separated because of this website, but the original file is tab separated.

Comment: I used your sample file, changed the delimiters to tab and ran the updated script.

Answer (score 1):

using **awk**

Based on your input I am assuming your data is sorted by first column i.e userID

```
awk 'userID==$1{ track[$4]++} userID!=$1{ printf userID"\t"; for(i in track) if(track[i]>=20) printf i" "; userID=$1; delete track; track[$4]++; printf RS;} END{printf userID"\t"; for(i in track) if(track[i]>=20) printf i" "; userID=$1; printf RS}' file
```

For better readability :

```
awk '
    userID==$1 { track[$4]++ } 
    userID!=$1 { printf userID"\t"; for(i in track) if(track[i]>=20) printf i" "; userID=$1; delete track; track[$4]++; printf RS;} 
    END        { printf userID"\t"; for(i in track) if(track[i]>=20) printf i" "; userID=$1; printf RS}' file
```

**Explanation :**

`userID==$1 { track[$4]++ }` : `userID` is a variable (which is initially null) and we are comparing it  with the first field in your data. For each user we are creating an associative array `track` which is using keys as the `trackID` and value as its count;

`userID!=$1 { printf userID"\t"; for(i in track) if(track[i]>20) printf i" "; userID=$1; delete track; track[$4]++; printf RS;}` :
If `userID!=$1` that means we are reading the record for a new user having userID different from the previous one. In that case print the `userID` , iterate through the array and if count>20 then print the trackID.

Same goes for the last record set in `END` block.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and such a well explained answer. My file is not sorted according to user ID. When I run your solution, I found following error: "Value too large for defined data type". As I mentioned above, my input file is more than 2 GB.